# Deserialize JSON into JPA managed entities with Jackson

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

When deserializing a JPA `@Entity` with Jackson, I'd like Jackson to operate on a managed instance if that exists, deserializing then all its properties on it; otherwise creating a new transient one.

Say I have a `Person` on the database as:

```
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name | favoriteHero |
+----+------+--------------+
| 21 | John | NULL         |
+----+------+--------------+
```

And I want to deserialize this JSON

```
{
    "id": 21,
    "favoriteHero": "Batman"
}
```

using

```
Person john = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);
```

then I need `john` being the JPA managed entity, first retrieved by `id` from the persistence context, then with `favoriteHero` set to *Batman*, so that

```
john.getId() == 21;
john.getName() == "John";
john.getFavoriteHero() == "Batman";
```

Is it possible?

I tried with a `JsonDeserializer`, but it would use the retrieved entity from the database and not proceed setting the values (and it can not fallback to a default deserialization if not found on the database).

Comment: I cannot use `@JsonCreator` since I cannot clutter the entity code with database layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with GSON, if that's what you mean: https://github.com/google/gson
Example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Person p = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
```

Comment: I need to stick with `Jackson`, since all the project uses it. Plus, the example you provide would not provide a managed entity (i.e. retrieved from the persistence context).

Answer (score 0):

This has already been done.  Why reinvent the wheel.  Use [Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/).

Comment: I cannot change the whole REST API on the project, I just need a Jackson way to deserialize JSON in a JPA-compatible way.

Comment: @MarkOfHall can you kindly provide some example of doing this with Spring Data Rest?